# Doctest fails in python3 but works if tested manually

Tags: python

I have just started learning python and I am following some online lectures from my university. I have just been introduced to writing doctests in scripts. Below is my code:

```
 """ Our first python source file. """

from operator import floordiv, mod 

def divide_exact(n,d):
    """ Return the quotient and remainder.

    >>> q, r = divide_exact(2013, 10)
    >>> q 
    201
    >>> r
    3
    """
    return floordiv(n, d), mod(n, d)
```

When I run

```
python3 -m doctest -v lec3video3
```

I pass 0 testcases. I get this error

```
    File "lec3video3test", line 7, in lec3video3test
Failed example:
    q, r = divide_exact(2013, 10)
Exception raised:
    Traceback (most recent call last):
      File "/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.7/lib/python3.7/doctest.py", line 1329, in __run
        compileflags, 1), test.globs)
      File "<doctest lec3video3test[0]>", line 1, in <module>
        q, r = divide_exact(2013, 10)
    NameError: name 'divide_exact' is not defined
```

I don't know why because I know my code works. What am I doing wrong? I have tested my code in interactive mode and everything is correct.

Comment: I got `IndentationError: unexpected indent` on the first line of your code. Is that a typo? If I remove it, I'm not able to reproduce the issue. You need to make a [mre].

Comment: Beside the point, but `divide_exact` does the exact same thing as `divmod`, which is a Python builtin

Comment: @wjandrea yeah, it was a typo. my bad, sorry. and I didn't know that divmod was a thing but cool! i was just using the professor's example. thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is an `IndentationError` in the current version of your code. However, I guess that's just an error which happened during copy and paste as you would get a completely different error message, then.

Regarding the `NameError` you're describing: If I put your given code

```py
""" Our first python source file. """

from operator import floordiv, mod 

def divide_exact(n,d):
    """ Return the quotient and remainder.

    >>> q, r = divide_exact(2013, 10)
    >>> q 
    201
    >>> r
    3
    """
    return floordiv(n, d), mod(n, d)
```

in a file `example.py` and call `doctest` with the following command, I get:

```
$ python3 -m doctest -v example.py
Trying:
    q, r = divide_exact(2013, 10)
Expecting nothing
ok
Trying:
    q 
Expecting:
    201
ok
Trying:
    r
Expecting:
    3
ok
1 items had no tests:
    example
1 items passed all tests:
   3 tests in example.divide_exact
3 tests in 2 items.
3 passed and 0 failed.
Test passed.
```

It says

```
1 items had no tests:
    example
```

because there are no tests in the module docstring. Other than that, all three tests in the function docstring for `divide_exact` do pass as expected.

So you will just have to make sure your file is in the correct folder and your command follows the required syntax for the `doctest` module.